# Add a field in Serializer depending on other field : django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a seriliazer:

```
class aaaser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client_code = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_status(self, obj):
        status_code = obj.status if obj.status else -1
        return status_code

    class Meta:
        model = models.Order
        fields = ('client_code', 'status', 'order_id', 'details')
```

In this seriliazer i want to add a field with name `cancel_reason` which should ONLY be added if value of `status == 5`.

```
class aaaser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client_code = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_status(self, obj):
        status_code = obj.status if obj.status else -1
        if status_code == 5:
            # this felt dumb but had to try!
            cancel_reason = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        return status_code

    def get_cancel_reason(self, obj):
        return "Dummy-reason"

    class Meta:
        model = models.Order
        fields = ('client_code', 'status', 'order_id', 'details')
```

**`^This Doesn't work`**

Please suggest a solution or a alternative to `SerializerMethodField` for this usecase.. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
class aaaser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client_code = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_status(self, obj):
        status_code = obj.status if obj.status else -1
        if status_code == 5:
            self.fields['cancel_reason'] = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        return status_code
```

as mentioned [here](http://masnun.com/2015/10/21/django-rest-framework-dynamic-fields-in-serializers.html) on how to add dynamic fields in serializer

Comment: Thanks this is useful. Though adding self.fields['cancel_reason'] will work only in __init__ func as field values are not checked after initialization. Works after this update!